# How to get value from a dynamic dropdown menu

Tags: javascript

I am creating a basic online price estimator, you can view it here https://jsfiddle.net/gc1bbc4t/#&togetherjs=4xeUE6l7Et (the code is displayed here but for some reason it doesnt actually calculate a total, it does on my PC)

I have made it so that when you choose your "fencing", a range of heights will drop down. Currently each fencing option has a value assigned to it. I am going to change this so that each height has a value assigned to it. My issue is that because I have a range of different height dropdowns that could appear how do i figure out which was has been selected and use that to calculate the total?

HTML -

```
<!doctype HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
    <title>Price Estimator</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="estimatorcalculations.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href="styles/cakeform.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body onload='hideTotal()'>
<form action="" id="cakeform" onsubmit="return false;">
   <fieldset>
    <legend>Estimate the cost of your fence</legend>

    <label >Fencing</label>

    <select id="fencing" name='fencing' onchange="calculateTotal()">
        <option value="None">Select Fencing</option>
        <option value="premiumTimber">Premium Timber</option>
        <option value="roughSawnTimber">Rough Sawn Timber</option>
    </select>

    <div class="container">
    <div class="premiumTimber">
        <label>Height</label>
        <select class="second-level-select">
            <option value="">-Height-</option>
            <option value="basic-ore-1">1m</option>
            <option value="basic-ore-2">2m</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="roughSawnTimber">
        <select class="second-level-select">
            <option value="">-Height-</option>
            <option value="omber-miner-1">1.5m</option>
            <option value="omber-miner-2">2.5m</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    </div>

    <br/>
    <label>Length (metres):</label> <input type="text"  name="mLength" onchange="calculateTotal()" id="mLength" />
    <br/>


    <label for='includecandles' class="inlinelabel">Do you need a fence removed?($5)</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="includecandles" name='includecandles' onclick="calculateTotal()" />


    <div id="totalPrice"></div>

    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fencing').bind('change', function() {
        var elements = $('div.container').children().hide(); // hide all the elements
        var value = $(this).val();

        if (value.length) { // if somethings' selected
            elements.filter('.' + value).show(); // show the ones we want
        }
    }).trigger('change');

    $('.second-level-select').bind('change', function() {
        var elements = $('div.second-level-container').children().hide(); // hide all the elements
        var value = $(this).val();

        if (value.length) { // if somethings' selected
            elements.filter('.' + value).show(); // show the ones we want
        }
    }).trigger('change');
});
</script>
```

JS -

```
var fencing_prices= new Array();
fencing_prices["None"]=0;
fencing_prices["premiumTimber"]=10;
fencing_prices["roughSawnTimber"]=5;

//This function finds the filling price based on the
//drop down selection
function getFencingPrice()
{
    var cakeFencingPrice=0;
    //Get a reference to the form id="cakeform"
    var theForm = document.forms["cakeform"];
    //Get a reference to the select id="fencing"
     var selectedFencing = theForm.elements["fencing"];

    //set cakeFilling Price equal to value user chose
    //For example filling_prices["Lemon".value] would be equal to 5
    cakeFencingPrice = fencing_prices[selectedFencing.value];

    //finally we return cakeFillingPrice
    return cakeFencingPrice;
}

function getLength()
{
    //Assume form with id="theform"
    var theForm = document.forms["cakeform"];
    //Get a reference to the TextBox
    var quantity = theForm.elements["mLength"];
    var howmany =0;
    //If the textbox is not blank
    if(quantity.value!="")
    {
        howmany = parseInt(quantity.value);
    }
    return howmany;
}
function getHeight() {
    var theForm = document.forms["cakeform"];

}
/*
function getHeight()
{
    //Assume form with id="theform"
    var theForm = document.forms["cakeform"];
    //Get a reference to the TextBox
    var quantity = theForm.elements["mHeight"];
    var howmany =0;
    //If the textbox is not blank
    if(quantity.value!="")
    {
        howmany = parseInt(quantity.value);
    }
    return howmany;
}
*/

//candlesPrice() finds the candles price based on a check box selection
function candlesPrice()
{
    var candlePrice=0;
    //Get a reference to the form id="cakeform"
    var theForm = document.forms["cakeform"];
    //Get a reference to the checkbox id="includecandles"
    var includeCandles = theForm.elements["includecandles"];

    //If they checked the box set candlePrice to 5
    if(includeCandles.checked==true)
    {
        candlePrice=5;
    }
    //finally we return the candlePrice
    return candlePrice;
}


function calculateTotal()
{
    //Here we get the total price by calling our function
    //Each function returns a number so by calling them we add the values they return together
    var fencePrice = (getFencingPrice() * getLength())+ candlesPrice();

    //display the result
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Total price for the fence $"+fencePrice;

}


function hideTotal()
{
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='none';
}
```

Comment: you means select ?

Comment: @Thamerbelfkih I am sorry, I dont understand what you are asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do the following:**

- You can get the height from the visible drop-down
- Remove the `onchange=calculateTotal` from the drop-down and put it inside of `$('#fencing').bind('change', function(){...}`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#fencing').bind('change', function() {
        calculateTotal();
       
        var elements = $('div.container').children().hide(); // hide all the elements
        var value = $(this).val();

        if (value.length) { // if somethings' selected
            elements.filter('.' + value).show(); // show the ones we want
        }
    }).trigger('change');
    
    $('.second-level-select').bind('change', function() {
        var elements = $('div.second-level-container').children().hide(); // hide all the elements
        var value = $(this).val();

        if (value.length) { // if somethings' selected
            elements.filter('.' + value).show(); // show the ones we want
        }
    }).trigger('change');
});

hideTotal();


var fencing_prices= new Array();
fencing_prices["None"]=0;
fencing_prices["premiumTimber"]=10;
fencing_prices["roughSawnTimber"]=5;

//This function finds the filling price based on the
//drop down selection
function getFencingPrice() {
    var cakeFencingPrice=0;
    //Get a reference to the form id="cakeform"
    var theForm = document.forms["cakeform"];
    //Get a reference to the select id="fencing"
     var selectedFencing = theForm.elements["fencing"];

    //set cakeFilling Price equal to value user chose
    //For example filling_prices["Lemon".value] would be equal to 5
    cakeFencingPrice = fencing_prices[selectedFencing.value];

    //finally we return cakeFillingPrice
    return cakeFencingPrice;
}

function getLength() {
    //Assume form with id="theform"
    var theForm = document.forms["cakeform"];
    //Get a reference to the TextBox
    var quantity = theForm.elements["mLength"];
    var howmany =0;
    //If the textbox is not blank
    if(quantity.value!="")
    {
        howmany = parseInt(quantity.value);
    }
    return howmany;
}
function getHeight() {
    var theForm = document.forms["cakeform"];

}

function getHeight() {
    if ($('.premiumTimber').find('select').is(":visible")) {
        return $('.premiumTimber').find('select').val();
    } else {
        return $('.roughSawnTimber').find('select').val();
    }
}


//candlesPrice() finds the candles price based on a check box selection
function candlesPrice() {
    var candlePrice=0;
    //Get a reference to the form id="cakeform"
    var theForm = document.forms["cakeform"];
    //Get a reference to the checkbox id="includecandles"
    var includeCandles = theForm.elements["includecandles"];

    //If they checked the box set candlePrice to 5
    if(includeCandles.checked==true)
    {
        candlePrice=5;
    }
    //finally we return the candlePrice
    return candlePrice;
}


function calculateTotal() {
    $('#selectedh').html(getHeight());
    //Here we get the total price by calling our function
    //Each function returns a number so by calling them we add the values they return together
    var fencePrice = (getFencingPrice() * getLength())+ candlesPrice();

    //display the result
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Total price for the fence $"+fencePrice;

}


function hideTotal()
{
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='none';
}
```

```html
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form action="" id="cakeform" onsubmit="return false;">
   <fieldset>
    <legend>Estimate the cost of your fence</legend>
 
    <label >Fencing</label>
 
    <select id="fencing" name='fencing' >
  <option value="None">Select Fencing</option>
  <option value="premiumTimber">Premium Timber</option>
  <option value="roughSawnTimber">Rough Sawn Timber</option>
    </select>
 
 <div class="container">
    <div class="premiumTimber">
  <label>Height</label>
        <select class="second-level-select" onchange="calculateTotal()">
            <option value="">-Height-</option>
            <option value="basic-ore-1">1m</option>
            <option value="basic-ore-2">2m</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="roughSawnTimber">
        <select class="second-level-select" onchange="calculateTotal()">
            <option value="">-Height-</option>
            <option value="omber-miner-1">1.5m</option>
            <option value="omber-miner-2">2.5m</option>
        </select>
    </div>
 </div>

    <br/>
 <label>Length (metres):</label> <input type="text"  name="mLength" onchange="calculateTotal()" id="mLength" />
 <br/>
 
  
 <label for='includecandles' class="inlinelabel">Do you need a fence removed?($5)</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="includecandles" name='includecandles' onclick="calculateTotal()" />

    <p>Selected Height</p>
    <p id='selectedh'></p>
    <div id="totalPrice"></div>
 
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked great